# is it possible to let List validation not set value when using poi to export to excel

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using poi `poi-ooxml-4.0.0` to export an excel in the spring boot java project, but shows error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: List validation with explicit values must specify at least one value
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFDataValidationConstraint.<init>(XSSFDataValidationConstraint.java:50) ~[poi-ooxml-4.0.0.jar!/:4.0.0]
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFDataValidationHelper.createExplicitListConstraint(XSSFDataValidationHelper.java:66) ~[poi-ooxml-4.0.0.jar!/:4.0.0]
    at com.sportswin.soa.zhuolianorg.repo.DataValidationHandler.lambda$afterSheetCreate$3(DataValidationHandler.java:67) ~[classes!/:na]
    at java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1289) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at com.sportswin.soa.zhuolianorg.repo.DataValidationHandler.afterSheetCreate(DataValidationHandler.java:61) ~[classes!/:na]
    at com.alibaba.excel.util.WriteHandlerUtils.afterSheetCreate(WriteHandlerUtils.java:103) ~[easyexcel-2.2.11.jar!/:na]
    at com.alibaba.excel.util.WriteHandlerUtils.afterSheetCreate(WriteHandlerUtils.java:93) ~[easyexcel-2.2.11.jar!/:na]
    at com.alibaba.excel.context.WriteContextImpl.initSheet(WriteContextImpl.java:188) ~[easyexcel-2.2.11.jar!/:na]
    at com.alibaba.excel.context.WriteContextImpl.currentSheet(WriteContextImpl.java:122) ~[easyexcel-2.2.11.jar!/:na]
    at com.alibaba.excel.write.ExcelBuilderImpl.addContent(ExcelBuilderImpl.java:53) ~[easyexcel-2.2.11.jar!/:na]
    at com.alibaba.excel.ExcelWriter.write(ExcelWriter.java:161) ~[easyexcel-2.2.11.jar!/:na]
    at com.alibaba.excel.ExcelWriter.write(ExcelWriter.java:146) ~[easyexcel-2.2.11.jar!/:na]
    at com.sportswin.soa.zhuolianorg.repo.UploadSparkUserDAO.addRemark(UploadSparkUserDAO.java:103) ~[classes!/:na]
```

the error is clear that tell me the List validation column value must set, but sometimes the data validation column did not have data, is it possible to output the excel without default value? like this:

[image]

Comment: The error is about an empty `java.lang.String[] listOfValues` in [DataValidationHelper.createExplicitListConstraint](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataValidationHelper.html#createExplicitListConstraint-java.lang.String:A-). In your picture it has 6 values. Nothing is set as the cell value. But that's not the cause of that error. So without having the code which invokes `DataValidationHelper.createExplicitListConstraint` and shows how  `java.lang.String[] listOfValues` gets created this is not reproducible.

Comment: Just looked deeper. Also an empty array `java.lang.String[] listOfValues` would work. So the `java.lang.String[] listOfValues` you are passing to `XSSFDataValidationHelper.createExplicitListConstraint` either must be `null` or of size 0 to throw that error.

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not show your code, as the comment said,check your listOfValues is null or the size is 0. The error message is clear, you could not pass null to the listOfValues. I predicate you generate the validation from some source of data in your code. So check the error columns data is null   or not. That's the problem happens, you should make sure all your validation column have at least one choice.